# There is no directive with exportAs set to ngbNav

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVtda.pn)

```
import { NgbNavConfig, NgbNavModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

i am getting this error in **angular 11** before i am using `ngbtab`  but same error i am getting on `ngbtab` also

Comment: Please read the following documentation: [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question, providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you missed the import, you are using some type of 'special routing' because by default, Angular loads the NgbModule in every component so u are doing something different, in my case I'm using Lazy Loading ngModules, so I need specify angular to import the NgbModule (that's why it says there is no directive).

To fix this error simply import the NgbModule in your module imports:

```
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@NgModule({
     declarations:[....],
     imports: [
         NgbModule
     ]
})
export class Whatever { }
```

Hope it was useful!!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue in this case :

- Create a new module
- Import NgbModule in this module
- Use <ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs"> in a component of this module
- Forgot to add my new module in app.module.ts !

hope this help